# Script to recursively grep data from certain files in the directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am making a simple shell script which will minimize the time I spend in searching all directories under a parent directory and grep some things inside some files. Here's my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
MainDir=/var/opt/database/1227-1239/

cd "$MainDir"

for dir in $(ls); do

grep -i "STAGE,te_start_seq Starting" "$dir"/his_file | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out

if [ -f "$dir"/sysconfig.out];
then
    grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
else
    grep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
fi

done
```

The script is supposed to grep the string `STAGE,te_start_seq Starting` under the file `his_file` then dump it `sst-logs.out` which it does. My problem though is the part in the `if` statement. The script should check the current directory for `sysconfig.out`, grep `drive model` and dump it to `sst-logs.out` if it exists, otherwise, change directory to `node0` then grep `physical memory size` from `setupsys.out` and dump it to `sst-logs.out`. My problem is, it seems the `if then else` statement seems not to work as it doesn`t dump any data at all but if i execute grep manually, i do have data.

What is wrong with my shell script? Is there any more efficient way in doing this?

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: I notice that you have `for dir in $(ls);`. You should [never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), because it's impossible to do reliably and there's always a better way. Try this instead: `for dir in *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one syntax error; you are missing a space before the `]` of the if statement. The line should be

```
if [ -f "$dir"/sysconfig.out ] ;
```

Strange that your script does not report that. Do you run it from cron? Before you start your script automatically, first make it sure that it works correctly. Add `echo` statements to debug your program:

```
if [ -f "$dir/sysconfig.out" ] ; then
  echo "$dir/sysconfig.out present"
  echo running grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out
  grep -A 1 "Drive Model" "$dir"/sysconfig.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
else
  echo "$dir/sysconfig.out absent"
  echo running rep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out
  grep -m 1 "Physical memory size" "$dir"/node0/setupsys.out | tail -1 >> /home/xtee/sst-logs.out
fi
```

Comment: Hi January. Thanks for the reply. Right now I am running manually, but planning to run from a cron job later. I will try your solution and feedback if it's okay or not :)